# Ansible skip import_playbook with variable definition

Tags: ansible

I have a `main.yaml` like below:

```
- import_playbook: 1.yaml
    
- import_playbook: 2.yaml
  vars:
    allow2: False 
  when: allow2
```

I want the playbook `2.yaml` can be skipped totally (not try to execute any tasks inside `2.yaml`).
But it looks all tasks in `2.yaml` will be called but not executed.

File `1.yaml`:

```
- name: Go1
  hosts: test
  gather_facts: false 

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Message from 1.yaml"
```

File `2.yaml`:

```
- name: Go2
  hosts: test
  gather_facts: false 
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Message from 2.yaml"
```

The output is:

```
$ ansible-playbook main.yaml 

PLAY [Go1] ***********
TASK [debug] *********
Thursday 05 October 2017  03:10:12 -0400 (0:00:00.116)       0:00:00.116 ****** 
ok: [test1] => {}

MSG:

Message from 1.yaml


PLAY [Go2] ************

TASK [debug] ************
Thursday 05 October 2017  03:10:12 -0400 (0:00:00.090)       0:00:00.206 ****** 
skipping: [test1]
```

The you can say the task in `2.yaml` also was called but skipped.
But I want no any tasks will be called in `2.yaml`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible this way.

Please see answer at serverfault about [import/include difference](https://serverfault.com/questions/875247/whats-the-difference-between-include-tasks-and-import-tasks/875292#875292).

`import_playbook` is static, so it's always done and `when` statements attached to everything inside it.

Comment: There is an issue raised for dynamic `include_playbook` functionality - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34281

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not need any conditional format and just skip running the playbook 2.yaml you may use tags by modifying the main.yaml as the following:

```
- import_playbook: 1.yaml
    
- import_playbook: 2.yaml
  tags: playbook_2
```

And run as by skipping tag playbook_2:

```
bill@inspiron:~/tmp_ansible$ ansible-playbook main.yaml --skip-tags=playbook_2
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Go1] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Message from 1.yaml"
}

PLAY [Go2] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```