# Access variables at play level

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I use `localhost` and `set_fact` to store variables and access them in different playbooks.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: set_variables
      set_fact:
        cloudinit_fqdn: 'server1.example.com'
        additional_container_config_values:
          security.nesting: 'false'
          security.privileged: 'false'
        cloudinit_network_raw:
          version: 2
          renderer: networkd
          ethernets:
            eth0:
              dhcp4: False
              addresses: [192.168.178.35/24]
              gateway4: 192.168.178.1
              nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.178.13]
```

Now I want to use the `cloudinit_fqdn` at `import_playbook`:

```yaml
- name: system configuration
  import_playbook: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['cloudinit_fqdn'] }}_server_config.yml"
```

I tried different ways to get that variable, but I get errors like:

> 'ERROR! 'hostvars' is undefined'

I am not able to get access to that variable by:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: '{{ vars }}'
```

> ERROR! 'debug' is not a valid attribute for a Play

How can I use a variable at play-level?

Comment: You should show use how you are really using those. _ERROR! 'debug' is not a valid attribute for a Play_, for example, shows that you are using this debug task outside of a play, which has nothing to do with the way you register your fact.

Comment: import_playbook provides the child plays with access to the parent facts - this is how I structure my automation in Ansible 2.9. A few things to check: ---1) are you able to debug: {{ vars }} within the parent play? ---2) do you have hosts: localhost in the child play? not hosts: {{ inventory }} ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your use case I've setup a short test to come around the syntax errors of the variable, as well the debug task.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Set variables
    set_fact:
      example_fqdn: 'test.example.com'

  - name: Show variables
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].example_fqdn }}"
```

While the example is working, adding

```yaml
- name: Import playbook
  import_playbook: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].example_fqdn }}.yml"
```

or even a simple

```yaml
- name: Import playbook
  import_playbook: "{{ example_fqdn }}.yml"
```

let the playbook run fail with

```
ERROR! 'hostvars' is undefined
ERROR! 'example_fqdn' is undefined
```

since the import is done during compile time, whereby the variable will be defined during runtime. Even not possible is

```yaml
- name: Import playbook
  import_playbook: "{{ to_import }}.yml"
  vars:
    to_import: "{{ example_fqdn }}"
```

as the import is static, not dynamic. [Importing playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html) and [Re-using playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-playbooks) seems not working in that way.

What is actually working is

```yaml
- name: Import playbook
  import_playbook: test.example.com.yml
```

**Furher Questions and Answers**

- [Ansible: `import_playbook` fails with variable undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560064/)
- [Ansible: Skip `import_playbook` with variable definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580030/)
- [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`](https://serverfault.com/questions/875247/whats-the-difference-between-include-tasks-and-import-tasks/875292#875292)